# Javascript count down with database input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
sset($_POST["confirm"])) {
 $check="select * from tbl_donate where receiverId='$username' and status = 'created'";
    $exc=mysqli_query($conn,$check);
    $match=mysqli_fetch_array($exc);

    $cElapseTime=$match['cElapseTime'];
    $timeCreated=$match['timeCreated'];
    $receiverId=$match['receiverId'];
    $senderId=$match['senderId'];
    $pop = $match['proof'];
    $projectId = $match['projectId'];
    $actlAmt = $match['amtRec'];
    //$errMsg = $projectId;
    $now=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $t1 = strtotime($timeCreated);
    $t2 = strtotime($cElapseTime);
    $t3 = strtotime($now);
   $diff = $t2 - $t3;
   $hours = gmdate("H:i:s", $diff);
```

i want to pass this as a count down to a javascript, and also after the countdown is zero, it should automatically stops the countdown and reload the page and update a column in the database.

i need help on this

Comment: Share what you have tried so far and what specifically you're having trouble with.

Comment: Please take the time to look at your post and confirm the code/presentation is correct. The formatting was off here and the first line is an obvious syntax error. You also have not asked a question..

Comment: <div id="response" style="border-color:#F00;color:#00F;font-size:30px;"> </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
          setInterval(function()
    {
     timezone: 'Africa/Lagos';
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.open("GET","request_rec.php",false);
     xmlhttp.send(null);
     document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     },1000);
          
          </script>

Comment: this is getting echo from the first code i sent, but it seems not working well